# How to extract numbers from excel cell

Tags: python, excel, split, xlrd

I want to get only the numbers from a cell (excel). I tried the following:

```
uzemelteto = first_sheet.cell(17, 11)
res = [int(i) for i in uzemelteto.split() if i.isdigit()]
print res
```

But it gives an error like: AttributeError: 'Cell' object has no attribute 'split'

How can I modify it, to be able to get only digits?

Comment: Try to cast `str` on `uzemelteto`.
To be sure, add this statement between the first and the second line:
`uzemelteto = str(uzemelteto)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`worksheet.cell()` returns an object, namely an instance of the class `Cell` ([docs](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.sheet.Cell)).

A Cell object has a property `value`, so instead of

```
uzemelteto.split()
```

use

```
uzemelteto.value.split()
```

or, to be super safe, because the type of cell.value may vary based on the content, you can use

```
str(uzemelteto.value).split()
```